# Handling integer overflows in MySQL ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

*I know this problem could be completely avoided by proper design like a BIGINT ID or a fractional timestamp, but those are beyond my power.*

A machine feeds data into a MySQL database with an integer ID and a second-precision timestamp. Data is being fed every 90 ms with the ID increased accordingly, i.e. from 1 to 91 to 181 etc. Since this incrementation happens several times per second, there are different IDs with the same timestamp. Also, the ID field is only an unsigned smallint, so there is an overflow when it reaches 65536.

I do need the data ordered by time, so a simple

```
ORDER BY timestamp ASC, ID ASC
```

would work for those cases where no overflow is present within the second covered by the timestamp. Unfortunately, with an overflow present the IDs 42, 132 and 222 would get sorted before 65308, 65398 and 65488.

Is there a way to do something like

```
ORDER BY
    timestamp ASC, 
    If((min(ID)<10000) and (max(ID)>60000), If(ID<10000, ID+65536, ID), ID)
```

with somehow specifying to which range the `min()` and `max()` should apply?

**EDIT 1:** The data is added in batches, so an `auto_increment` column (which I have to separate records, even though redundant) will not necessarily reflect the correct temporal order.

**EDIT 2:** See line in italic at the top.

Comment: Can you add another auto-incrementing ID column to the table & use that for ordering?

Comment: Paul and I assume the ID column is AUTO_INCREMENT... but is it? Or does the "machine" increment and you have no control over it?

Because, if it's left to pure MySQL the counter would overflow, but the old data has to be purged or REPLACEd, otherwise you'd get duplicate key entry failures. Can you go into a bit more detail on this?

Comment: @YetiCGN - I was proposing a separate id column defined as auto-increment in the table, so it would not matter if the machine generated ID were auto-incremented or wraps around.

Comment: @PaulF It matters if there is already another AUTO_INCREMENT column like id.
`SQL Error (1075): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

Comment: So, with further clarification after the edit, let's sum up:

1. ID column is set by the data source, beyond your control, but wraps around at 65,536.
2. The data is not inserted real-time but in batches, meaning increased precision for the timestamp column is useless because several entries will have the same fractional timestamp.
3. You already have another primary key AUTO_INCREMENT column but somehow the data is not inserted in temporal order so even BIGINT won't help here.

Tricky ...

Answer (score 1):

How much of the database design is under your power? Obviously you cannot change the width of the primary key field. If you could ALTER the precision of the timestamp column, you could include [fractions of a second](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html).

An alternative is to issue timed SQL statements to the database to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT counter every n seconds so that the overflow does not occur *within* a timestamp interval. However, this needs to be timed to a 90 ms precision, obviously.

If all else fails, copy the data to another table with the help of triggers and calculate the order criterion while doing so. This could be slow with pure SQL but a simple script might do the trick.

**EDIT:** I've quickly recreated your schema and populated it with some testdata to come up with this beast of a query with the same assumption you made, that the overlap area can only lie between 10,000 and 60,000:

`SELECT *, (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 1, 0) FROM test t WHERE t.timestamp = test.timestamp AND t.id NOT BETWEEN 10000 AND 60000) AS has_overlap FROM test
ORDER BY timestamp ASC, IF(has_overlap AND id < 10000, id + 65536, id)`

Now you just have to test it for performance, because the subquery might kill you. If that is the case, pre-calculate it before you make the ordered SELECT query.

Comment: I don't have any influence as to which data is written into the database when. All I can do is write SQL code (or something else further downstream) to extract and manipulate data.

Comment: But in your first sentence you state "some of it is beyond my power", implying that some of it (the database design) is within your power. How much and what exactly? :-)